# Stop animation by setInterval inside a function from another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my message system if new message come, its call a function and this function display a scroll by jquery animation in setInterval.

Now I want stop it from another function how check if no new message.

I call this function to display scroll:

```
function scroll(userID) { 
  $('.scroll'+userID).css('left','250px').show().html(''+ userID +' sent a new massage').animate({
      left: '-='+(250+149)
      }, 2000, function() {
      scrollt(userID);
  });
 window.Ccolor = setInterval(function(){$('.popup'+userID).css('background-color','red');}, 2000);
}
```

Another function check by setInterval for new mail

```
function update() {
//code get userID have no new mail but scroll is running 
//on his minimize popup

//want to stop scroll by uesrID

//Tried
clearInterval(Ccolor); //not work also can`t set userID
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: mEssage; mAssage is a different word :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a flag in update() function if new message is coming and in scroll() function use setTimeout instead of setInterval and call scroll if flag is set to true

```
    function scroll(userID) { 
       $('.scroll'+userID).css('left','250px').show().html(''+ userID +' sent a new massage').animate({
      left: '-='+(250+149)
      }, 2000, function() {
      scrollt(userID);
  });
 window.Ccolor = setTimeout(function(){$('.popup'+userID).css('background-color','red');}, 2000);
}
    function update() {
    var flag=false;
    //set flag=true is new message come
    if(flag===true)
     scroll(userId);
    else
    setTimeout(update,2000);
    }
```

Am assuming that you have your own logic to know if userId is new or not or you can also set data-* attribute in you html element